# is it possible to submit two .apks under one app

Tags: android, android-activity, apk

I have a bit of situation where I want to use another app features in my main app. I wanted to submit two .apks so user could install both apps at same time. I know how to communicate between two apps. But is it possible to submit two apps so user can get both apps one installation?

Please help.

Comment: Do you mean download one .apk under a single application? There is file expansion, but I don't know if it accepts apk's as a file type. It would seem as though Google would do things to combat this (downloading hidden secondary apps behind the main apps that users don't know about), but I could be wrong.

Comment: The cleanest technical solution would probably be to merge the two APKs into one.  It sounds like the second APK might not be your work though, so that may be a licensing issue - but you'd need a valid license to distribute the other APK even as is, too.

Comment: How do you communicate between two apps?

Answer (score 0):

Yep it's possible, in Developer console you have to first upload your main apk (up to 50MB), and after that you can upload another one, up to 10GB.

http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

Comment: The expansion capability is for application resources, not for program code such as an entire APK.  Technically, there are ways to load "data" as code, but it is extremely tricky to do so on Android.  So this is not meaningfully an answer to the question which was asked.